# Retrieve an Image from a POST request

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to send a picture to my java servlet (hosted on amazon ec2) to later transfer it to amazon s3 and wonder how to retrieve the Image from the post request.

### Upload Code

The request is sent through iOS RestKit API like this (pic.imageData is a NSData type):

```
RKParams* params = [RKParams params];

[params setValue:pic.dateTaken forParam:@"dateTaken"];
[params setValue:pic.dateUploaded forParam:@"dateUploaded"];

[params setData:pic.imageData MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" forParam:@"image"];

[RKClient sharedClient].username = deviceID;
[RKClient sharedClient].password = sessionKey;

[RKClient sharedClient].authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic;

uploadPictureRequest = [[RKClient sharedClient] post:kUploadPictureServlet params:params delegate:self];
```

### Parsing Code Stub

This is how I parse the other 2 parameters on the Java servlet:

```
double dateTaken = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("dateTaken"));
double dateUploaded = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("dateUploaded"));
```

### Question

The question is: **how do I retrieve and parse the image on my server?**

Comment: My suggestion might be a bit off topic but you also have the option of base64 encoded images. Though not very efficient but they have served me well.

http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to

Comment: which servlet container you are using?

Comment: @AnupamSaini im very new to server programming so simply using restkit seemed to be the easiest solution.

Comment: @RameshPVK apache tomcat i believe

Comment: @RameshPVK the instance image on my ec2 says: AMI: ElasticBeanstalk-Tomcat6-64bit-201202071737 (ami-d5ec3cbc)

Comment: Which servlet version it supports? I have added an answer can you check that.

Comment: No problem Luis , it never hurts to be aware of the alternatives :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines of this, using [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/index.html):

```
 // or @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
         throws ServletException, IOException {
     if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
         final FileItemFactory   factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
         final ServletFileUpload upload  = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

         try {
             final List items = upload.parseRequest(request);

             for (Iterator itr = items.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
                 final FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();

                 if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    /*
                     * TODO: (for you)
                     *  1. Verify that file item is an image type.
                     *  2. And do whatever you want with it.
                     */
                 }
             }
         } catch (FileUploadException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }
```

Refer to the [`FileItem`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html) API reference doc to determine what to do next.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the apache commons fileupload says the specifies the following: if an HTTP request is submitted using the POST method, and with a content type of "multipart/form-data", then FileUpload can parse that request, and make the results available in a manner easily used by the caller. I my request compliant with this?

Comment: @LuisOscar: Try and you shall find the answer.

Comment: @LuisOscar: Your request is indeed a `POST`. From what I gather from [RestKit](http://restkit.org/)'s [RKParams reference documentation](http://restkit.org/api/0.10.0/Classes/RKParams.html), it should be a multi-part message.

Comment: thanks, im trying to install the commons fileupload to java so i can test it ill get back to you in a bit.

Comment: Ok i managed to import the commons but im getting the following warnings: List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized. Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator<E> should be parameterized.

Comment: @LuisOscar: it's a warning, not an errror (so you can live with it, if you understand it) and that's because the Apache Commons File Upload library does not support generics and returns raw types. If you want to not have this warning, add the annotation `@suppresswarnings("rawtypes")` to the method.

Comment: @LuisOscar: if this one doesn't work (depends on your exact Java compiler version), use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` instead.

Comment: that did remove the warning, but when i run it on my server i get this exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream. So i thing im not getting the class to the server... would happen to know the solution for this? thanks

Comment: @nevermind that last message, turns out i need to add the commons.io since its a dependency... lol java is so weird

Comment: @LuisOscar: Define weird? You expect it to know auto-magically what you need? If you import a class from a package, it may request to import other classes from other packages, but it's up to your build to have all the required bundles on the classpath. Seems pretty common and similar to every other language to me: compiled languages with static libraries, C# with the Java equivalent, etc...

Comment: well the problem was more like i didnt know because eclipse didnt say it needed it and when runing from eclipse to the server the library was not being exported. But no i ran into another problem. I do find the image like this if ("image/jpeg".equals(item.getContentType())) but the item.get() gives me a byte[] type or a InputStream, SHould i convert to a File type to pass to s3? or get the lenght and input stream and pass it like that to s3? thanks

Comment: haha sorry again, just figured it out, i can simply pass the inputstream along with the content lenght to the amazon request constructor method. thanks for all your help

Answer (score 4):

`Servlet 3.0` has support for reading multipart data. MutlipartConfig support in `Servlet 3.0` If a servelt is annotated using `@MutlipartConfig` annotation, the container is responsible for making the Multipart parts available through

```
HttpServletRequest.getParts()
HttpServletRequest.getPart("name");
```

**References:**

- [Servlet 3.0 File Upload handing files and params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217611/java-servlet-jsp-image-upload-along-with-form-values/11219548#11219548)
- [Servlet 3.0 File upload Example](http://rameshpvk.blogspot.in/2012/06/fileuplod-using-servlet-30.html)

Comment: It seems i cant use this approach because im running tomcat 6 and according to this site: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html I only have 2.x serlvets

Comment: then you should use commons apache file upload

Comment: @Lion: it's also the way that works only on recent containers :) Not everybody is that lucky, whereas the lib-way is relatively easy and backward- and forward-compatible. If you have a Servlet 3+ capable container, then I'd definitely go for that then.